# Recharts Add Currency Format to Area Chart Value

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I have a graph like this, I want to add currency format but rechart give me raw number
[image: recharts area graph]

Here is my code now

```
 <ResponsiveContainer height={300}>
                                  <AreaChart
                                    data={dataTransaksi}
                                    margin={{
                                      top: 20,
                                      right: 30,
                                      left: 0,
                                      bottom: 0,
                                    }}
                                  >
                                    <XAxis
                                      dataKey="name"
                                      style={{ fill: "#01204C" }}
                                    />
                                    <YAxis
                                      style={{ fill: "#01204C" }}
                                      tickFormatter={(value) =>
                                        new Intl.NumberFormat("id-ID", {
                                          notation: "compact",
                                          compactDisplay: "short",
                                        }).format(value)
                                      }
                                    />
                                    <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
                                    <Tooltip />
                                    <Area
                                      type="monotone"
                                      dataKey="Total Transaksi"
                                      stroke="#14B8A6"
                                      fill="#14B8A6"
                                    />
                                    <Brush />
                                  </AreaChart>
                                </ResponsiveContainer>
```

How to make my area chart "Total Transaksi" value auto formatted to Currency value?